# Identity under smiley face

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

This problem is asking for the identity under smiley face (sf).  Since a sf a = a AND also c sf c = c, how do I know which is the identity under smiley face sf?

Comment: This is assuming you're talking about a group structure: It is possible that multiple elements of a group will satisfy $x^2=x$; what defines the identity is that $ex=xe=x$ for all $x$ in the group. Here, there is no element with that property (it isn't even a group). However, $a$ does satisfy $ax=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Trying to absorb this answer......so which element is the identity and why?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to read the table.

Comment: Can you show the actual question too -- in its precise wording, not just the given data? This operation is not a group operation, as evidenced e.g. by the columns of a and of c. This operation doesn't have an identity, although it does have a one-sided one. So, what exactly was the question?

Answer (score 1):

The identity element $x$ doesn't just need to satisfy $x\cdot x$ = $x$ (I use $\cdot$ instead of smiley); it needs to satisfy $x\cdot y=y$ and $y\cdot x=y$ for *every* $y$.

So, for instance, $c$ isn't the identity here because $c\cdot a=b$, and $a\not=b$. Does this make sense?

---

To give a concrete example, consider the integers with multiplication. Then both $x=0$ and $x=1$ satisfy $x\cdot x=x$, but only $x=1$ satisfies $x\cdot y=y=y\cdot x$ for all $y$.